# Swift: Build Failed but no errors

Tags: swift, barcode, rsbarcodes

I'm currently trying to implement this GitHub: https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift I have followed the instructions like so:

- Add RSBarcodes_Swift as a submodule by opening the Terminal, cd-ing into your top-level project directory, and entering the command git submodule add https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift.git

  **Added with no errors**
- Open the RSBarcodes_Swift folder, and drag RSBarcodes.xcodeproj into the file navigator of your app project.

  **I'm assuming he meant project navigator here, which I did**
- In Xcode, navigate to the target configuration window by clicking on the blue project icon, and selecting the application target under the "Targets" heading in the sidebar. Ensure that the deployment target of RSBarcodes.framework matches that of the application target.

  **Yup, It is set to 7.1**
- In the tab bar at the top of that window, open the "Build Phases" panel.
  Expand the "Target Dependencies" group, and add RSBarcodes.framework.

  **Coudn't add 'RSBarcodes.framework' as it only gave me the option for 'RSBarcodes' Which I added as assumed the .framework was added wrongly**
- Click on the + button at the top left of the panel and select "New Copy Files Phase". Rename this new phase to "Copy Frameworks", set the "Destination" to "Frameworks", and add RSBarcodes.framework.

  **Added, No Problems**

The next set of instructions are:

Place an **UIViewController** in storyboard and set **RSCodeReaderViewController** based class as its custom class and it almost there, focus mark layer and corners layer is already there working for you. There are to handlers, one for the single tap on the screen along with the focus mark and the other is detected objects handler, which all detected will come to you. Set them up in **viewDidLoad()** or some place more suitable:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.focusMarkLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

self.cornersLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor

self.tapHandler = { point in
    println(point)
}

self.barcodesHandler = { barcodes in
    for barcode in barcodes {
        println(barcode)
    }
}
}
```

I have followed those, the only thing that I did differently was add a **UIButton** to the main ViewController and add **performSegueWithIdentifier** to show the **RSCodeReaderViewController** as it was inaccessible

I have uploaded the project here: http://www.filedropper.com/barcodetestreader if you would like to see it. Could someone please tell me what is going on or if you encounter any errors?

Comment: How do you know the build failed if you got no errors???

Comment: It said Build Failed. Instead of Build Succeeded :S

Comment: And what does the build log say?

Comment: I cant see anything in the Build Log

Comment: Wait? I'm a little new to this. is that the console that would usually display the println etc.... ?

Comment: No, you've got to poke around for it a bit.  I don't have an Xcode at hand to tell you exactly what, though.  But if you poke at a warning message the right way in the errors/tab it will take you to the build log.

Comment: But there are no errors showing ?

Comment: You must at least have a warning message.

Comment: There is this: Applications using Launch Screen Files and targetting iOS 7.1 and earlier need to also include a Launch Image in an Asset Catalog.

Comment: If your code doesn't show any error and Xcode 6.1 it is not compiling you might need to delete xcode DerivedData folder (user Library/Developer) and also delete Xcode file called com.apple.dt.Xcode and folder com.apple.dt.XcodeDeviceMonitor inside users library/caches

Answer (score 1):

Don't make this:

Yup, It is set to 7.1

It's OK! :

Coudn't add 'RSBarcodes.framework' as it only gave me the option for 'RSBarcodes' Which I added as assumed the .framework was added wrongly.
Your must add RSBarcodes ! Without .frameworks!

Do this and it will work:

In the tab bar at the top of that window, open the "Build Phases" panel. Expand the "**Link Binary With Libraries**" group, and add RSBarcodes.framework.

Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can use CocoaPods() or Carthage to install RSBarcodes_Swift.

CocoaPods:

> pod 'RSBarcodes_Swift', '~> 0.0.5'

in your Podfile.

Carthage:

> github "yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift" >= 0.0.5

in your Cartfile.